# If statement overwriting when it shouldn't (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement, int

I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm inputting tTitle as 100 and tJson as mm but  it keeps returning 6 when I should be getting 5. As you can see with "all([])" i've tried other ways but nothing seems to be working.

```
                if "any" or "Any" or "ANY" in tTitle:
                     tCAT = 0
                if "100" in tTitle:
                     tCAT = 1
                if "100" in tTitle and tJson == "tloz2":
                     tCAT = 3
                if "45" in tTitle and tJson == "ss":
                     tCAT = 4
                if all(["100" in tTitle, tJson == "mm"]):
                     tCAT = 5
                if all(["any" or "Any" or "ANY" in tTitle, tJson == "mm"]):
                     tCAT = 6
                else:
                     tCAT = 0
```

Comment: And another new programmer trips over boolean logic.

Comment: I feel like I should just make it a string

Comment: `if "any" in tTitle.lower():` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the last if ：`if all(["any" or "Any" or "ANY" in tTitle, tJson == "mm"]):
                     tCAT = 6` is acctually means this:

```
if all([("any") or ("Any") or ("ANY" in tTitle), tJson == "mm"]):
    tCAT = 6
```

so it will be true because `("any") or ("Any") or ("ANY" in tTitle)` is True

Comment: Should I close it off with () so ("ANY") - If so it still returns wrong num (6)

Comment: @user1043816, no, I mean what your code is like that, and what you mean should be `"any" in tTitle or "Any" in tTitle or "Any" in tTitle`

Comment: Ah I didn't think it would go for it that way, I'll keep that in mind thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by simply tTitle.lower() and then only requested to find one type "any" thank you gnibbler